# showcurrentlocation and compass controls not appearing on Google map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-toolbar

The showcurrentlocaion and compass controls are not appearing on the google map fragment.  However, they were showing before I added the navigation drawer and toolbar to the project, but afterwards they are not showing. Could this be because the toolbar is right on top of the map and hiding those controls? By the way, the zoom control, which appears at the bottom right corner of the screen, shows and works fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

**Activity**

```
    package dev.com.transitone;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    UiSettings mapSettings;
    private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 101;
    private static final String fineRequest= "Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION";
    private String TAG = "MapDemo";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        requestPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);

       /* if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            requestPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }*/


        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    protected void requestPermission(String permissionType, int
            requestCode) {
        int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                permissionType);
        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{permissionType}, requestCode
            );
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[]
                                                   grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE: {
                if (grantResults.length == 0
                        || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to show location - permission required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mapSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();

            mapSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            mapSettings.setCompassEnabled(true);

        }

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        /*LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));*/
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


}
```

**Layout**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="dev.com.transitone.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="dev.com.transitone.MapsActivity" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Manifest**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="dev.com.transitone">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!--<application-->
        <!--android:allowBackup="true"-->
        <!--android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"-->
        <!--android:label="@string/app_name"-->
        <!--android:supportsRtl="true"-->
        <!--android:theme="@style/AppTheme">-->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
            >
            <intent-filter
                android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            >

        </activity>
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what it looks like now?

Comment: @DanielNugent Hi Daniel.  I updated the post with a link to the screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: For some reason, the map fragment is taking up the entire screen and the toolbar is sitting right on top of the map which is why those controls are blocked from view.  How do I structure the layout file such that the map comes after the toolbar?

Comment: Solved. I placed the map fragment into a relative layout container. It is fine now.

Comment: Please check my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985787/cant-get-my-location-and-location-button-not-show/37612352#37612352

Answer (score 1):

Compass control won't show until view's rotation change. See the gif below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This line is the key for CoordinatorLayout

```
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

<FrameLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
  >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:transitionName="mapView"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.GoogleMapsActivity"
    />
```