# can't get my location and location button not show

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, material-design

after i make drawer menu and floating button why my maps can't get my location and location button not show, and why the search place button when it clicked so that force stop?
before i add drawer menu and floating button, it's all okay..
Before
[image: [pict]BEFORE] 
After
[image: [pict]AFTER]

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.emergency.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:background="@color/background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include layout="@layout/activity_maps"/>

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
                android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/white"
                fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
                fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/half_black"
                fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

                <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/action_a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                    fab:fab_title="Tambal Ban"
                    fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
                    fab:fab_size="mini"/>
                <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/action_b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                    fab:fab_title="ATM"
                    fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
                    fab:fab_size="mini"/>
                <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/action_c"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                    fab:fab_title="WC Umum"
                    fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
                    fab:fab_size="mini"/>

            </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_menu"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigasi"
        android:layout_gravity="start">
        <!--perintah buat nampilin menu utama kemudian bisa di slide yang ada menu adalah yang layout_gravity-->


    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView >
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

activity_maps.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_tempat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context="com.emergency.MapsActivity" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Bsearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff4081"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map"
        android:text="Search Place"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="onSearch"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Put your error log please

Comment: hey, this is my logcat http://pastebin.com/BhE3VAnF  sorry using external link because if i write in post it will be limited.

Comment: Directly from your logcat : **Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.**. Do you have these two?

Comment: **update** i try to go MapsActivity without running MainActivity and all okay, i can get location and location button show

Comment: anyone can help me?please

Answer (score 1):

For some reason `SupportMapFragment` does not show my location button (or compass icon) when its placed inside `<DrawerLayout>` (<- as a root view), but there is a solution:

Put the whole `<DrawerLayout>` in `<RelativeLayout>` and remove `<include>` and just put whole `activity_maps.xml` in `activity_main`. Also to make it look better I would recommend moving `activity_maps.xml` and make a fragment from it, and then instead of `<include>` you would have:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
    class="com.yourpackage.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

You will have separated logic only for map in the fragment, an all activity stuff in activity. And we all know that `MainActivity` tends to grow over time for many reasons ;)